# Definition of "first embarkation point" for trip to Indonesia

Tags: air-travel, transit, covid-19, terminology, indonesia

I have a code shared flight linked on Singapore Air from LAX to Manado, Indonesia through Singapore. The LAX/SIN flight is Singapore Air, then Scoot Air SIN/Manado. I check my bags all the way through from LAX to Manado and have an 8 hour layover in SIN without leaving airport.
I have to have a PCR test as follows: "Passengers must have a negative Covid-19 PCR test result taken within 48 hours before departure from the first embarkation point."
QUESTION: Is my first embarkation point SIN or Manado?
QUESTION 2: Is it 48 physical hours or clock/calendar hours (not accounting for time zone difference)?

Comment: This might help answer Q2 https://www.sonictraveltesting.com.au/travel-testing-calculator/

Answer (score 6):

- First embarkation point: LAX
- Covid test within 48 hours of flight departure at LAX

Comment: You answer the OP's situation, but you don't answer the general question (What's the definition?). Cases one might wonder about: What if they had two separate tickets? What if one takes a ship from Hawaii to Los Angeles? What's the maximum time for two tickets to be one journey? (Not saying that indonesia will even have a clear definition, but anything to make this more generic/sourced would probably be good)